# Remove item with empty value in django dictionary

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I want to remove dictionary item on my list.

```
Animals = ['dog', 'cat', 'fish', 'goat']
Owner = ['Nash', 'Luffy', '', '']

C = dict(zip(Animals, Owner))
C = {'dog':'Nash', 'cat':'Luffy', 'fish':'', 'goat':''}
```

What should I do to achieve the result below:

```
C =  {'dog':'Nash', 'cat':'Luffy'}
```

Comment: `dict([(i,j) for i, j in zip(Animals, Owner) if j != ''])`

Comment: @AvinashRaj well that won't reduce any iterations I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a [`dict` comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
>>> {k: v for k, v in C.items() if v != ''}
{'dog': 'Nash', 'cat': 'Luffy'}
```

or using a `for` loop:

```
for k, v in C.items():
    if v == '':
        del(C[k])
```

Answer (score -2):

too easy just do this

```
mylist = {}
count = 0
for i in animals:
    mylist[i] = owner[count]
    count += 1
```

hope it helps : )